# Why multiply 1.0/255, when convert to float type?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Why multiply 1.0/255, when convert to float type?

```
Mat src,dst;
src.convertTo(dst, CV_32F, 1.0/255);
```

Comment: that's a **scale** factor, not an offset(addition) think of it like `dst = src/255`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not added `1.0/255` - it is scaling by that factor.  In other words, it is taking a integer value in the range 0..255 and converting to a float in the range 0.0 .. 1.0

Comment: I know: a*I(x,y)+b, but why we need 1/255 * (0..255)? Why need a integer value from the range 0..255 converting to a float in the range 0.0 .. 1.0?

Comment: @magrif because **conventionally** if the image is of type `CV_8U` (`uchar`, `uint8`, `byte` ) the pixel range is in `[0, 255]`, but when the type is `CV_32F` (`float`) or `CV_64F` (`double`) the pixel range is in `[0, 1]`. Also, if the image is of type `CV_16U` (`unsigned short`) the range is in `[0, 65535]`.

Comment: @Miki From a practical point of view, for what need convert from integer to float-point?
I thought func convertTo(dst, CV_32F) automatically multiplied 1.0/255 during convert, if float at range [0..1].

Comment: @magrif it doesn't. `convertTo` only converts type (with `saturated_cast`).  You **need to specify** the needed scaling. Why you need to convert? Well, that depends only on your needs :D

Comment: @magrif: for example imshow will interpret float value of <= 0 as black and float value of >= 1 as full white. values between 0 and 1 will be gray